# SonarQube 4.5 - Can't View Rule Details

Tags: sonarqube

I am set up as an administrator in our SonarQube 4.5 instance.  When I select a rule from either the Rules or the Quality Profiles sections, nothing is displayed on the right hand details pane.  There is a quick flash of a waiting/loading icon, but then nothing.

I found this in the logs:

```
2014.11.03 11:06:16 ERROR web[rails]    On line #2 of /opt/sonarqube-4.5/temp/ror/motionchart/app/views/motion_chart/_widget_body.html.erb

1: <%
2:    metrics = widget_properties["metric-x"].key + ',' + widget_properties["metric-y"].key + ',' + widget_properties["metric-color"].key + ',' + widget_properties["metric-size"].key
3:    ws_url = "metrics=#{metrics}" + url_params
4: %>
5: <% content_for :script do %>
```

Is this related? How can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

I restarted the server and tried to view a rule's details, but still nothing is displayed.  The error hasn't re-occured in the logs.

**UPDATE TWO**

I opened the JavaScrip console (I'm using FF 33.0) and when I click on the rule it says

```
ReferenceError: moment is not defined
```

Does that provide useful info?

Anyway, now I'm getting info on the right pane.  Yay!  But there isn't a way for me to edit/disable it.

Comment: Could you please check the JavaScript console of your browser when a rule does not show? This could provide useful information about what's wrong.

Comment: I logged out as myself and logged in as our "admin" user and the ability to deactivate the rule is now available.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that rebuilding ES indexes will do the job. For that delete, after backup ^^, the "data/es" folder of your SQ instance, then restart your server. Indexes will be rebuilt (it may take some time depending on the size/number of your projects).